# Pass argument to Javascript metod from Ajax ActionLink MVC3.0

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have a problem sending parameter (Id) to javascript function. Let me tell you about the underlying idea: I have a Training model and every training model has 1 Survey. What i do in below code is to generate a pop-up link for each Training that employee takes and display a pop-up window. For this I used the Ajax ActionLink and in each part to show the popup window I cretead a div with the id of Training. So when onComplete I call a javascript function openPopup to show the popup window but it does not. So in conclusion I have different div's in which I will popup a window and I want to pass the id of div to the javascript function. Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (id) {
            $(id).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Anket',
                width: 500,
                height: 'auto',
                modal: true
            });
        });
        function openPopup(id) {
            $(id).dialog("open");
        }
    </script>

   foreach (var training in Model.TrainingList)
   {
      <tr>
        <td class="view_detail_label">
                        Eğitim Adı
         </td>
          <td>

          @Ajax.ActionLink(training.Name.Name,
                           "AddSurvey", 
          new { employeeId = Model.Id, trainingId = training.Id },
           new AjaxOptions
             {
            UpdateTargetId = training.Id.ToString(),
              HttpMethod = "GET",
              InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
               LoadingElementId = "context",
               OnComplete = "openPopup('"+training.Id.ToString()+"')"
                 })

               <div id="@training.Id" style="display:none;"/>  

                    </td>                        
                </tr>                 
               }           
            }
        </table>
```

Comment: I don't use razor and ajax.actionLinks, so this is is just guess :). Maybe you should add @ before training in this line: OnComplete = "openPopup('"+training.Id.ToString()+"')". Anyway check if anything is passed to openPopup at all.

Comment: In my generated html code the link is shown as below:
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-complete="openPopup('1692')" data-ajax-loading="#context" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#1692" href="/Home/AddSurvey?employeeId=692&amp;trainingId=1692">"Effective Test Design" Eğitimi</a>


<div id="1692" style="display:none;"></div>

Comment: Maybe you need to call it like this $("#"+id).dialog({...

Comment: I tried that too but it does not work

Comment: Huh, i would refactor using Darin Dimitrov solution as it is better approach. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a plain `Html.ActionLink` that you could unobtrusively AJAXify which gives you far more flexibility. Also you seem to have used some `id` argument of your `document.ready` function which doesn't exist and has nowhere to come from. The `document.ready` callback doesn't take any arguments.

So:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.addSurvey').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                context: this,
                success: function(result) {
                    $(this).next('.result').html(result).dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        title: 'Anket',
                        width: 500,
                        height: 'auto',
                        modal: true
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<table>
    @foreach (var training in Model.TrainingList)
    {
       <tr>
           <td class="view_detail_label">
               Eğitim Adı
           </td>
           <td>
               @Html.ActionLink(
                   training.Name.Name, 
                   AddSurvey, 
                   new { 
                       employeeId = Model.Id, 
                       trainingId = training.Id 
                   },
                   new {
                       @class = "addSurvey"
                   }
               )
               <div class="result"></div>
           </td>                        
       </tr>                 
    }
</table>
```

Also I would very strongly recommend you moving your script out in a separate javascript file and not mix your markup with scripts.

Remark: since you are opening the result of the AJAX call in a modal dialog I don't quite see the point of having a result div in each row. You could simply move it out from the `<table>` and have a single one.

Comment: Will this work for more than 1 link? I have worked with 1 link and when i had multi links, the div id  to be updated on javascript created me problems.

Comment: Of course that it will work. Notice how I am using a class selector. But the more important question you have to ask yourself is why do you need to have multiple divs since you are opening a modal dialog. I'd rather change this and have a single result div somwhere outside the table. Then it would not really matter on which link you clicked.

Comment: I placed div outside the table, changed actionlink with the one you provided and replaced javascript method with yours, it does not open popup window. What am i missing?

Comment: Is the AJAX request being sent? Are you getting a response from the server? What happened when you inspected this request in the Network tab of your javascript debugging tool? Is there some error in the javascript Console? What's the value of `$(this).next('.result')` inside the success AJAX callback - does it return any elements?

Comment: Ajax request issent in the controller addsurvey breakpoint is hit and it return, but it does not open in popup window when i right click and open it in new tab it opens in new tab. There are no errors in javascript console too

Comment: How can i see the value of $(this).next('.result'). In the network console is sent
http://localhost:50735/Home/AddSurvey?employeeId=692&trainingId=1695&_=1369059723430

Comment: You could put a `console.log($(this).next('.result'));` inside the success callback and watch the Console window. But you seem to have mentioned something about putting the div outside the table. If this is the case it is obvious that the `$(this).next('.result')` selector won't return you any results since the div no longer exists there. Give it an unique id and adapt your selector.

Comment: If i move it back into the table will it work? If i give an unique id it comes to my first problem of passsing Training Id to javascrpt code.

Comment: In order to pass the training id to javascript simply use HTML5 data-* attribute on the anchor: `new { @class = "addSurvey", id = training.Id }` and then inside your AJAX success callback if you wanted to retrieve this id simply use `$(this).data('id');`. That's basic jQuery. I would recommend you reading the documentation and getting through some getting started tutorials to familiarize with the basic functionality of the javascript framework you are using.

Comment: I moved the div inside table and it works, but in this case when I open and close pop up I can not open it again but when i refresh the page the links are active again. What might be the reason for that

Comment: The reason is that you are probably updating the table and the `.click` handler to which you subscribed in your document.ready is no longer attached to the new elements that you inserted. You could subscribe to the .click event in a *lively* manner using the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method: `$(document).on('click', '.addSurvey', function() { ... });`.

Comment: I used it as follows:

  $(document).on('click', '.addSurvey', function () {
        $('.addSurvey').click(function () {

But the it does not popup and replace the page

Comment: Why did you put a `.click` handler inside the `.on` handler? The purpose of the `.on` function is to subscribe to the click event, so don't repeat this subscription once again. Just place your `$.ajax` call inside. I really would recommend you reading some getting started tutorials about jQuery as this discussion no longer has any relation to ASP.NET MVC. Maybe start a new question specific to it.